# Video Game Engine Gravity

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was trying to make a game engine that used gravity. I tried making it so your character moves down one pixel (Up in a Winforms)every time a timer goes off, and if it's touching the ground, it goes up until it stop touching it. However, it makes your character bounce up and down continually. Is there any other way I could go about this?

Comment: Don't just post the code of your entire program. Make sure your question is concise and to the point. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Check if subtracting 1 pixel would put you below ground FIRST, and don't subtract if so.